# Debian Buster GUI freezes up with Nvidia graphics

Tags: debian, x11, nvidia

I recently built a new system, and my graphics are having... problems. The GUI will freeze up frequently and for minutes at a time. I'm running the proprietary drivers, and didn't have this problem with nouveau, but nouveau also didn't recognize my GPU or let me set up my second monitor.

Running `dmesg | grep NVRM` yields

```
[    3.909853] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.66  Mon May  1 15:29:16 PDT 2017 (using threaded interrupts)
[  350.982860] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:09:00: GPU-7276b506-d343-19d6-901c-e9b2d011f0b4
[  350.982868] NVRM: GPU Board Serial Number: 
[  350.982873] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:09:00): 32, Channel ID 00000020 intr 00040000
[  355.100050] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:09:00): 32, Channel ID 00000028 intr 00040000
[  409.548334] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:09:00): 31, Ch 00000028, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  413.293746] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:09:00): 32, Channel ID 00000028 intr 00040000
[ 4082.537408] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:09:00): 32, Channel ID 00000020 intr 00040000
```

but these [Xid](http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/index.html) errors don't mean a whole lot to me.

`xrandr` gives

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2806 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 256mm
   1440x900      59.89*+
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1366x768+1440+132 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.86*+
   1920x1080     59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti. Any ideas on what I might try?

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet, so have to ask here. How did you install the proprietary drivers? I've done it a number of times on my systems, and keep forgetting the exact steps, but I just run the one-file download from nvidia from the shell, and it guides me (generally run from terminal with root - without X). It's important that it compiles necessary libs with your current kernel libs.

Also, did you check /usr/bin/nvidia-settings ? (just to do a general check on settings, I guess).

What about the Xorg.0.log? It should give more details on errors than dmesg.

Comment: I installed it from the Debian repos, as per [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#NVIDIA_Proprietary_Driver) (though using the Buster repos rather than the Jessie ones). I can open nvidia-settings, but I don't see anything in particular that seems unusual - what should I be looking for?

Comment: You can consider downloading a driver from nvidia and running their installer. They are pretty good.

Comment: I haven't had luck with those in the past, but I'll give it a shot!

Comment: It seems I have the same driver as the current version distributed by nvidia.

Comment: My Xorg.0.log [here](https://pastebin.com/Thr2y6TU)

Comment: I see multiple pauses from logind, you should check dbus messages. A [similar example](https://chrisdown.name/2016/10/18/x-freezing-systemd-logind-got-pause.html). I think I can still recommend downloading from nvidia (even if they are same firmware) and installing their version.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [NVIDIA's XID Errors page](http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/):

> The Xid message is an error report from the NVIDIA driver that is printed to the operating system's kernel log or event log. Xid messages indicate that a general GPU error occurred, most often due to the driver programming the GPU incorrectly or to corruption of the commands sent to the GPU. The messages can be indicative of a hardware problem, an NVIDIA software problem, or a user application problem.

```
[  350.982873] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:09:00): 32, Channel ID 00000020 intr 00040000
```

`PCI:0000:09:00` is the device ID, and `32` is [XID error id](http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/#topic_4), in this case:

> Invalid or corrupted push buffer stream

---

1. You can try reinstalling all nvidia packages (`apt purge nvidia.`) Debian provides.
2. If that does not help, then try the [newest drivers from NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html).